# Php reorder and add to csv file

Tags: php, csv

I need to have a script that I can upload a CSV to and have it output the contents in a new order with some fields removed and some added. I have tried getting the csv into an array but emails seem to break it. An input might look like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
name, addr, phon, emal
...
```

The output would need to be changed to:

```
col4, col1, col3, col5
emal, name, addr, stat
...
```

Notice col3 is gone and col5 is added. col5 is the same value for every row.

I was doing this with a foreach loop. Which worked but its kind of slow. I dont know if there is a better or faster way.

Edit:

The answer seems to work but it raises two other features that will help:

One, I have a field that includes a date and time like `1/31/15 23:59`. is there an easy way to strip the last 6 characters?

Two, can we skip a line if say `col3` has data? I have a refunded date column that I would like to skip over if theres a date in it. Its blank otherwise. I know I can use isset but I dont know how to make the loop skip and continue if `col3` isset. Also I dont know if isset might still be TRUE if theres no data since the column still exists

Comment: Without code it is difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: The code I had didn't work at all and was not very good. I was hoping for something original from someone more experienced than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $sInFile  = 'infile.csv';
    $sOutFile = 'outfile.csv';

    $iRow = 0;
    if( ( $rHandle = fopen( $sInFile, "r")) !== FALSE ) 
    {
        while( ( $aData = fgetcsv( $rHandle, 1000, ",") ) !== FALSE ) 
        {
            // Skip headers.
            if( $iRow != 0 )
            {
                $iCountColumns = count( $aData );
                for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountColumns; ++$i )
                {
                    // Source
                    // name, addr, phon, emal
                    $sTmp  = '';
                    $sTmp .= $aData[ 3 ];
                    $sTmp .= ', ';
                    $sTmp .= $aData[ 0 ];
                    $sTmp .= ', ';
                    $sTmp .= $aData[ 1 ];
                    $sTmp .= ', ';
                    $sTmp .= 'CONSTANT!'; 
                    $sTmp .= "\n"; 
                    // Output
                    // emal, name, addr, stat
                }
                file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sTmp, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
            }
            ++$iRow;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If I set the input file as `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` would it be able to directly access the upload or do I need to save it to a location and trigger this function?

Comment: $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; will not give you a file location just the name. You need to move the file from it's temporary upload location to a specified directory and parse from there.

Comment: Ok, That seems okay, two new problems maybe you can solve. One, I have a field that includes a date and time like `1/31/15 23:59`. is there an easy way to strip the last 6 characters? Two, can we skip a line if say `col3` has data? I have a refunded date column that I would like to skip over if theres a date in it. Its blank otherwise. I know I can use `isset` but I dont know how to make the loop skip and continue if col3 isset. Also I dont know if isset might still be TRUE if theres no data since the column still exists.

Comment: use explode on data then set to first array key for date. $aBadData = explode( ' ', $sBadDate );  $sFixedData = $aBadDate[ 0 ]; Or use substr( $sBadDate, -6 ); To skip col3 just do a if( !empty( $aData[ 3 ] ) continue; to go to next loop. Avoid isset at all costs and realize that empty does empty and isset check together.